Center of gravity of slanted cylinder
Trying to solve the problem of the buckling of a water storage tower. As the storage tank displaced, the center of gravity/mass moves. Water which once occupied a cylindrical volume is now occupying the one of a slanted cylinder.

I was unable to derive the equations. One set is given by Wolfram and another by a Russian book (Feodosyev: Selected problems and questions in strength of materials).
It is a tricky problem, analogous to simply finding the centroid of a slanted cylinder.
Any help will be appreciated (and no it is not a homework problem :-)

Same question here

We use cylindrical coordinates with the $z$-axis aligned with the axis of symmetry of the cylinder, and the $x$-axis aligned with the direction the cylinder has been tilted.  As is standard, we define $\theta$ such that $x = r \cos \theta$.  In terms of this, the free surface of the water is given by the equation
$$
z = h + \alpha x = h + \alpha r \cos \theta
$$
where $\alpha \equiv \tan \phi$.  The volume of integration is then given by
$$
0 \leq r \leq R \qquad 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi \qquad 0 \leq z \leq h + \alpha r \cos \theta.
$$
Finally, note that the volume element in cylindrical polar coordinates is $dV = r \, dr \, d\theta \, dz$, and the density of the water is related to its mass by $M = \rho \pi h R^2$.
It is then relatively straightforward to find the coordinates for the centroid of the water;  the only complication is that we have to take care with the order in which we evaluate the integrals.  For the $x$-coordinate we have
\begin{align*}
x_{CM} &= \frac{\rho}{M} \int_0^R \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^{h + \alpha r \cos \theta} (r \cos \theta) r \, dr \, d\theta \, dz \\
&= \frac{\rho}{M} \int_0^R \int_0^{2 \pi} ( h r^2 \cos \theta + \alpha r^3 \cos^2 \theta ) \, dr \, d \theta & \text{(integrating over $z$)}\\
&= \frac{\rho \pi }{M} \int_0^R \left( \alpha r^3 \right) \, dr & \text{(integrating over $\theta$)} \\
&= \frac{\alpha \rho \pi R^4}{4M} = \frac{\alpha R^2}{4 h} .
\end{align*}
This agrees with the MathWorld definition if we note that $h = \frac{1}{2}(h_1 + h_2)$ and $\alpha = (h_2 - h_1)/2R$.
The $z$-coordinate of the CM can be found by replacing the $(r \cos \theta)$ factor in the integral above with $z$;  the resulting calculations are a little more complicated but not fundamentally more difficult.

Updated figure to better reflect my understanding of the solution. Regretfully, not allowed to express thanks.

@victor the best way to express thanks is accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark under the voting options on the left of the answer.

Hum, on second thought is'nt your solution assuming that we have a simusoidal distribution of the water elevation, when in actuality it ought to be linear?

@victor:  No, it's assuming that the height $z$ is linear in the Cartesian coordinate $x$.  It only looks sinusoidal in the later part of the derivation because $x$ depends on the angular coordinate $\theta$ in a sinusoidal way.

@Michael: may I communicate with you offline (saouma@colorado.edu)
